# #endif Header Guard not closing

Tags: c++, header, guard

**EDIT: It seems the error is occurring from my std::ostream&write(std::ostream& ostr) declaration as well as my int mdays(int mon) const declaration. When I comment those two functions out, the #endif guard no longer presents an error, but I'm not sure why there would be any problem with these two declarations.**

I've written a header file for a program I'm writing, but according to my code editor, the #endif header is highlighted in red meaning something is preventing it from closing. I've run through my declarations several times and it seems like everything is in place, so I'm confused as to why I am getting this error. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef SICT_DATE_H__
#define SICT_DATE_H__

//readErrorCode_ definitions
#define NO_ERROR 0 //no error date if valid
#define CIN_FAILED 1 //istream failed when entering information
#define YEAR_ERROR 2 //year value is invalid
#define MON_ERROR 3 //month value is invalid
#define DAY_ERROR 4 //day value is invalid

namespace sict {

class Date {
  int year_; //holds year; a four digit int between MIN_YEAR and MAX_YEAR
  int mon_; //month of the year, between 1 to 12
  int day_; //day of the month, not that a leap year in February is 29 days, (see mday())
  int readErrorCode_; //holds an error code with which the caller program can reference
  //to find out if the date value is valid and if not, which part is erroneous.
  int value() const; //function already implemented
  void errCode(int errorCode); //sets the readErrorCode_ member variable to one of
  //the values mentioned above
  void isValid(); //determine is date values are within range
  //Constructors
public:
  Date(); //default constructor: sets year_, mon_ and day_ to "0" and readErrorCode_ to NO_ERROR
  Date(int year, int month, int day); //three argument constructor: accepts three arguments to set values
  //of year_, mon_ and day_ attributes. Also sets readErrorCode_ to NO_ERROR

  //comparison logical operator overloads
  bool operator==(const Date& D)const;
  bool operator!=(const Date& D)const;
  bool operator<(const Date& D)const;
  bool operator>(const Date& D)const;
  bool operator<=(const Date& D)const;
  bool operator>=(const Date& D)const;

  int mdays(int mon)const; //function is already implemented and provided

  //accessor or getter member functions
  int errCode()const; //returns readErrorCode_ value
  bool bad()const; //returns true if readErrorCode_ is not equal to zero

  //IO member functions
  std::istream& read(std::istream& istr);//reads date in the following format: YYY?MM?DD
  std::ostream& write(std::ostream& ostr)const;
};

  //writes the date using ostr argument in the following format
  //YYY/MM/DD then return the ostr
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Date& D);
  std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Date& D);
}
#endif
```

Comment: Either that's an editor bug, or you have invalid syntax somewhere in the middle that is messing up the editor (editor bug either way)

Comment: Note that names containing multiple consecutive underscores are reserved for the C++ implementation - you should not be creating such names in your own code.

Comment: Compiles fine in my editor after these changes:
- line 5: added extra '/' to be a comment line
- line 26: removed line feed to resume comment

Comment: I added the extra / on line 5, I must have accidentally removed it when transferring my code here, but for line 26 what do you mean by removed line feed to resume comment?

Comment: @Glaz Your comment after your first constructor is split over 2 lines

Comment: I removed all of the comments to see if there were any problems, but it seems like that's not the issue. I think I might just have to start from scratch because I can't pick on where this error is coming from.

Comment: Maybe your editor's syntax checker has a bug. It probably does not handle namespaces correctly.

Comment: What editor is it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Atom

Comment: @Glaz: There have been over 400 released versions of that editor. Perhaps you can be more... specific?

Comment: I am using version 1.18.0 x64 on Mac, but it seems like the issue is only occurring now with the std::ostream& write(std::ostream& ostr)const; declaration. When I comment it out, the guard works.

Comment: Parsing bug then isn't it. Report it to the developers. I can't see a fix in the changelog for 1.90.0

Comment: This is not a direct solution for your issue, but a piece of advice. I would recommend using `#pragma once` at the beginning of header files instead of include guards. This is a controversial thing however, most compilers support it so that you don't have to worry about manually placing include guards.

Comment: Yeah but be careful with #pragma once, because it's based on the file name, not the file itself, so 2 files with a same name would generate a conflict, which can be avoided with common head guards :)